# Get the text content before child elements and text content after child elements?

Tags: javascript, xml

In the markup below, I know that I can get the full text content of the text element with `textEl.textContent`. But how would I do if I wanted to get the part of textContent that is before the elements children `But you` and the textContent after `yes` as two separate strings.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
  <g font-family="Verdana" font-size="45" >
    <text x="200" y="150" fill="blue" >
      But you
        <tspan dx="2em" dy="-50" font-weight="bold" fill="red" >
          are
        </tspan>
        <tspan dy="100">
           a peach!
        </tspan>
      yes
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this. Take the relevant nodeTypes

```js
const xmlString = `<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
  <g font-family="Verdana" font-size="45" >
    <text x="200" y="150" fill="blue" >
      But you
        <tspan dx="2em" dy="-50" font-weight="bold" fill="red" >
          are
        </tspan>
        <tspan dy="100">
           a peach!
        </tspan>
      yes
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>`
let parser = new DOMParser()
let doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "application/xml")

const cn = [...doc.querySelector("[fill=blue]").childNodes];

// reduce
let node3 = cn.reduce((acc, node) => {
  if (node.nodeType === 3) {
    const txt = node.textContent.trim();
    if (txt !== "") acc.push(txt);
  }
  return acc;
}, [])
console.log(node3)

// or filter plus map
node3 = cn.filter(node => node.nodeType === 3 && node.textContent.trim() !== "")
          .map(node => node.textContent.trim())
console.log(node3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `textEl.childNodes` which is an array of all child nodes to textEl including elements and text content.